# samba share write privileges lost

Tags: permissions, samba, ntfs, fstab

I had a samba shared drive that use to work fine for my ubuntu workstation but wasn't available on Windows computers. The setup allowed for anonymous users to access it and this is not permitted on Windows (unless some settings are changed)
To enable access to Windows running computers, I created users and passwords for all who wanted to connect to it.

Now, Windows users can read and write on it but I can't write on my ubuntu station. I also have problems mounting it at startup, the fstab file is no longer working.

The drive fs is **NTFS** and I think this is the main culprit. I tried to chmod and chown the folder but nothing changed: all files and folder are 755.

But I must admit that I am very confused as to what is really happening here.

My fstab file is copied here:

```
//192.168.1.2/ext4tb /mnt/ext4tb cifs ,credentials=/home/frepie/.smbcredentials,iocharset=utf8,vers=3.0,file_mode=0777,dir_mode=0777 0 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems problem in samba configuration. Try to create share like this:

```
[global]
   workgroup = WORKGROUP
   guest account = nobody
   security = user
   map to guest = bad user
[Test]
    path = /pathtoshare
    writable = yes
    printable = no
    only guest = yes
    public = yes
    guest ok = yes
    guest only = yes
    guest account = nobody
    browsable = yes
```